# $http, 404 код не ошибка?

Tags: http, angularjs

Имею такой код:

```
$http.get('someUrl').then(function(response){
    //что-то
}, function(error){
    //что-то
});
```

Сервер не знает someUrl, присылает 404, но выполняется первый callback, почему? Версия angular.js 1.3.15.

**Обновление**

Попробовал через success и error методы - то же самое.

Ни одна ошибка 4хх не вызывает callback error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`then` срабатывает в любом случае, так как сам `$http.get()` возвращает promise. `Error` - случай должен произойти программно или протоколом. `404` - это код ошибки прокола `http`, а не протокола работы `js`, `angular` или `promise`. Если тебе нужно обработать именно ошибку `404`, то обрабатывай ее явно. Пиши в первом `callback` соответствующую проверку. Если так нужно прям работать с исключениями, то тебе ничто не мешает сделать что-то вроде:

```
if (response.code === 404) throw Error({error: 404, errorMessage: "Нет такого ресурса."});
```

Можешь сделать это явно в первом `callback` или определить свой собственный тип "ресурса": https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource - тут у тебя большие возможности самому определять поведение.